# Computing dilutions

Tags: percentages, ratio

I have a source bottle that is $32$ oz. at $10\%$ concentration.

Customer support said I need $1.5$ ounce per $10$ gallons for the final product?  What is this final product concentration?  How do I figure that out?

How will I dilute future batches of different final product size (1 gallon, 2 gallon, etc.) to match this final product concentration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.

To figure out the volume ratio, convert gallons to ounces.

There are $128$ ounces in a gallon, so $1280$ in $10$.

Therefore, the final product concentration is $\dfrac {1.5}{1280}\times 10\%\approx0.012\%.$

If you need $ 1.5$ ounce for $10$ gallons, you need $0.15$ ounce per $1$ gallon.

Comment: you don't actually have to calculate the final product concentration to figure out how to dilute future batches of different size -- just make it proportional